# How to combine values from different rows using a common field in python? updated

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am new to python and would like your help if possible. I have a .csv file that contains multiple rows. In one column I have Country, other column I have id and in other I have latitude and longitude. I would like to combine into a new data frame unique values of country and latitude and longitude with all ids. To make it easier, I have this input df example:

```
Country id  longitude   latitude
Angola  Pable   17.470  -12.245
Angola  Juan    17.470  -12.245
Albania Dimitri 20.032  41.141
Albania Dinko   20.032  41.141
United States   John    -112.599    45.705
United States   Paul    -112.599    45.705
United States   David   -112.599    45.705
```

I have tried:

```
df1 = df.groupby('Country').apply(lambda x: ','.join(x.id))
```

But it is not working.

The output I'm looking for is:

```
Country id  longitude   latitude
Angola  Pable, Juan 17.470  -12.245
Albania Dimitri, Dinko  20.032  41.141
United States   John, Paul, David   -112.599    45.705
```

I expected this output as a pandas data frame, which I will be using to plot a map using plotly in python. Any ideas? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

```
print(
    df.groupby("Country")
    .agg({"id": ", ".join, "longitude": "first", "latitude": "first"})
    .reset_index()
)
```

Prints:

```
         Country                 id  longitude  latitude
0        Albania     Dimitri, Dinko     20.032    41.141
1         Angola        Pable, Juan     17.470   -12.245
2  United States  John, Paul, David   -112.599    45.705
```